# Rails App Single Sign In for Multiple Organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Background**

Devise User contain the organization_id as association belongs_to Organization.

Currently sign in url for user in Rails App is

http://localhost:3000/users/organizations/1/sign_in

Above Url help me to find the user on basis of username & organization while sign_in session.

User Model validates username unique in scope of organization.

**Need to achieve**

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

As Sign in Url for the all organization.

Current sign in url is Org dependent after acheiving above it will be converted to organization independent.

Can any one suggest a possible solution, which allow me to create the multiple user having same username in different organization, so on sign in it allows user to go their respective organization.

Other solution are also Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have multiple organization and you want to separate data between them. If that is the case you may want to consider multi-tenancy. Simple implementation of that is [acts_as_tenant gem](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant).

Than you simply scope that "membership"  that would contain your username for that particular organization. records scoped with organization will have default scope on organization_id, so they can duplicate everything else and stay "clean"

Maybe not the fastest setup, but if you want to have multiple organizations - the easiest I have tried.